# In a series of insert queries, last pdo insert does not commit to database

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am inserting a series of rows into a database using a prepared statement.  The problem I am running into is that the last iteration does not get inserted.  The code is following:

```
          $sql = 'INSERT INTO ReportDataLoggerTbl (
              date,
              dataTypeID,
              ClientID,
              dataVal
          ) VALUES (
              :timestamp,
              :dataType,
              :clientID,
              :encoded
          )';
      $cdsLink->beginTransaction();

      $q = $cdsLink->prepare($sql);
      foreach ($orderRows as $orderInfo) {
         // Get client
         $clientID = isset($orderInfo['ClientID']) === true ? $orderInfo['ClientID'] : 0;

         // Encode array
         $encoded = json_encode($orderInfo);

         $q->bindvalue(':timestamp', $timestamp, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $q->bindvalue(':dataType', $dataType, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $q->bindvalue(':clientID', $clientID, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $q->bindvalue(':encoded', $encoded, \PDO::PARAM_STR);

          $q->execute();
      }//end foreach

      $cdsLink->commit();
```

There are a total of 33 sets to be inserted into the database.  When all is said and done, the first 32 are in the database while the last one is not.  Any ideas?  Google hasn't really helped on this one.

Comment: there is really no reason why it wouldn't insert the last row. does `count($orderRows)` give you 33?

Comment: How are you checking/processing errors? Could the last one be failing and you just don't notice because it isn't displayed?

Comment: It does.  And I can print out the values, and all 33 print.  There are no errors either, so a try/catch doesn't help either.

Comment: Does it insert all 33 if you use the auto commit mode (remove `beginTransaction()` and `commmit()`)?

Comment: @Michael Unfortunately, no.  That was the way I originally had it too.  If I remove those, nothing changes.

Comment: By default, PDO does not throw exceptions on errors. You would need to call `$q->ErrorInfo()` after each execute to see if any errors have occurred. Alternatively, you can set up PDO to throw exceptions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

Comment: The problem may not be in the (posted) code, but in the data being inserted maybe? The way it's formatted. There might be an ending comma. Hard to say.

Comment: 1. Are all of the 'rows' to be inserted unique?
2. Does the table have an auto_incremented primary key?

Comment: @Duroth I have tried that as well to no avail.  No errors are being thrown in any form.

Comment: @Fred I can manually run the query and it inserts without issue, so it does not appear to be the data.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler 1. None of the rows are unique.  2.  Yes, there is an auto_incremented primary key - ReportDataLoggerID

Comment: If you print/echo `$q->rowCount()` after each execute, do you get 32 or 33(different echo's, each should be '1')?

Comment: Have you tried using `bindParam` instead of `bindvalue`? Plus, I don't know if the lowercase `v` in `bindvalue` makes any difference. I couldn't find anything on Google about that, yet I doubt it.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler The number is correct (Just tried).  Unless my counting is off.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have not.  I will give that a shot as well.

Comment: If the number of rowCount() == 1 is correct, are you sure there is nothing else in the script that deletes the last row, and are you sure that only 32 rows are being inserted?

Comment: @MichaelWheeler This is the last bit of code that runs, so I am 99.999999% sure nothing deletes the last row.  Also, I print out the rowCount along with one of the values, and there is a 1:1 relationship between the two values, so I am fairly certain on the number of rows being inserted as well as what says is being inserted.

Comment: How are you checking to see how many rows are in the database?

Comment: I actually run the following query directly on the database to verify the last item was actually inserted: `SELECT * FROM ReportDataLoggerTbl l WHERE l.DataVal LIKE '%230069%'`, and 0 rows are returned.  Though when I check for any of the other rows, 1 row is returned.

Comment: @MichaelWheeler You were mostly correct.  While the row was not being deleted, it was being overwritten.  I found the issue with it, and it is now resolved.  Thank you for the help.  Move your comment to an answer, and I will credit you with it.  Thanks again.